# How to remote debug spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, debugging

I wrote the following docker files and docker-compose files to run the spring app through Docker and remotely debug in the development environment.

dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy as base
WORKDIR /member
COPY gradle/ gradle
COPY settings.gradle gradlew build.gradle ./
RUN ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
COPY src ./src

FROM base as development
CMD ["./gradlew", "bootRun", "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000'"]

FROM base as build
RUN ./gradlew build

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-jammy as production
COPY --from=build /member/build/libs/*SNAPSHOT.jar /member.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","/member.jar"]
```

docker-compose.development.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  member:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./:/member
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    command: redis-server --port 6379
    container_name: redis_member
    hostname: redis_member
    labels:
      - "name=redis"
      - "mode=standalone"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Then, run the `docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up --build` command to run the container and attempt `telnet localhost 8000`, but Connection closed by foreign host.

The development environment is vscode, and the launch.json configuration is as follows.

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Remote Debug",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "localhost",
            "port": 8000,
        }
    ]
}
```

Running an app in debug mode in vscode will cause a timeout.

I want to know what's wrong. thank you.